# Como alterar o Texto e o ícone de um label usando JS ou JQuery - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Preciso setar a Descrição (`EnderecoTipoDescricao`) e o ícone (`icon fa-home`) no evento `change` de um `SELECT`. Para cada row o field "EnderecoTipoDescricao" possui um id cujo índice é incrementado: id="panel-title[i] indo de 0 até ... . Ao selecionar uma opçao no select, eu pego o Índice da row e com ele poderei setar o id field id="panel-title[i] correspondente à row. Não sei como setar o texto e o ícone da descriçao corrente conforme a opçao selecionada no selec (entrega ou Outro). Alguém sabe como fazer?

***RAZOR***

```
<h3 class="panel-title" id="panel-title[i]"><i class="icon fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>@Model.PessoasEnderecosViewModel[i].EnderecoTipoDescricao</h3>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label asp-for="PessoasEnderecosViewModel[i].EnderecoTipoId" class="control-label lb-endereco-tipo">Tipo de Endereço</label>
    <select asp-for="PessoasEnderecosViewModel[i].EnderecoTipoId" asp-items="@Model.PessoasEnderecosViewModel[i].EnderecosTipos" data-id="@Model.PessoasEnderecosViewModel[i].EnderecoTipoId" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control sel-endereco-tipo"><option value=""></option></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoasEnderecosViewModel[i].EnderecoTipoId" class="text-danger val-endereco-tipo"></span>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$('#div-enderecos').on("change", ".sel-endereco-tipo", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Pegar o índice
    var rowIndice = $(this).closest('.row').index();

    //Setar o texto e o ícone do field  panel-title[rowIndice ]???????????
});
```

OPÇOES NO SELECT

1 - ENTREGA (MUDAR O ÍCONE PARA icon fa-truck)
2 - OUTRO (MUDAR O ÍCONE PARA icon glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin)

Comment: Pergunta não ficou clara, cade o `SELECT` nessa pergunta? o que realmente quer fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar, encontrei uma solução para meu problema e espero que isso possa ajudar a quem precisar futuramente:

SOLUÇÃO:

```
$('#div-enderecos').on("change", ".sel-endereco-tipo", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var rowIndice = $(this).closest('.row').index();

    //Setar o Field
    var selectoption = document.getElementById("PessoasEnderecosViewModel_" + rowIndice + "__EnderecoTipoId");
    var optionText = selectoption.options[selectoption.selectedIndex].text;
    var enderecoTipoId = $("#PessoasEnderecosViewModel_" + rowIndice + "__EnderecoTipoId").val();
    var txt = document.getElementById('panel-title[' + rowIndice + ']');

    $("#PessoasEnderecosViewModel_" + rowIndice + "__EnderecoTipoDescricao").val(optionText);

    switch (enderecoTipoId) {
        case '1':                  
            txt.innerHTML = '<i class="icon fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + optionText + '';
            break;
        case '2':
            txt.innerHTML = '<i class="icon fa-building" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + optionText + '';
            break;
        case '3':
            txt.innerHTML = '<i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + optionText + '';
            break;
        case '4':
            txt.innerHTML = '<i class="icon fa-truck" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + optionText + '';
            break;
        case '5':
            txt.innerHTML = '<i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + optionText + '';
            break;
        case '6':
            txt.innerHTML = '<i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + optionText + '';
            break;
        case '7':
            txt.innerHTML = '<i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + optionText + '';
            break;
    }

});
```